# Nested Query Variable

Tags: sql, variables, subquery

Lets say I have a database that has a table that has a column of countries (COUNTRIES), a table that has a column for states and a column for the country that state is in (STATES), and a table has a column for cities and a column for the state that city is in (CITIES). I want to write a query that outputs a country, a state in that country, and how many cities are in that state

```
USA     Ohio    65
USA     Maine   52
           etc.....
```

My outer query is something like

```
SELECT COUNTRIES.country, STATES.state, COUNT(CITIES.city)
FROM COUNTRIES, STATES, CITIES
WHERE COUNTRIES.country = STATES.country AND 
      STATES.city = CITIES.city AND 
      EXISTS...
```

In that exists statement I want to write a nested subquery that will pull all of the cities out for a particular state for the COUNT function to count. Is there a way for me to write a variable or something similar that will pull out the cities only for a certain state?

Sorry if this is a confusing example, but the actual query I am trying to write this for is even more difficult to explain. Basically (using this example) my subquery is pulling out every city in every single state. I need to change that because if I am trying to count the number of cities in Arizona, I don't want Seattle or De Moines popping up.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Country, State, count(city) as Citycount
from Countries
inner join States on countries.country = states.country
inner join cities on states.state = cities.state
group by country, state
```